# Basic message_bus gem setup on Rails 5.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message-bus

I'm attempting to setup MessageBus gem ( https://github.com/SamSaffron/message_bus ) on a fresh install of Rails 5.04

So far I've

1. run `bundle`,
2. added `message-bus.js` and included it in the `application.js`
3. created an initializer
4. ran a rails scaffold generator
5. started a client in `request.js` that is subscribed to `/TestChannel`

When I go and test the app, it looks like the client is polling (based on the server logs), however, when I try and send a message in rails console, the client does not receive it. Yet per the server logs, it appears to attempt to send it.

**Example:**

Rails Console:

`MessageBus.publish "/TestChannel", "hello"` in rails console

Server Log:

`=> Delivering messages [] to client e4ac8e6cfeb340a8a389468bf0536053 for user  (chunked)`

Browser:
Nothing triggered.

Any help getting the client to trigger would be appreciated.